# How to convert Nested json to datatable using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, datatable

Hi I am calling a webapi from C#. It returns json data. It's a nested JSON. How to convert this JSON string to Datatable. I have read many posts suggesting to use a class, but my json string has multiple branches. How to convert this Json string to Datatable without using a class:

```
"PricedItineraries": {
        "AirItinerary": {
            "OriginDestinationOptions": {
                "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                    "FlightSegment": [{
                        "DepartureAirport": {
                            "LocationCode": "JFK"
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                            "LocationCode": "LAX"
                        },
                        "MarketingAirline": {
                            "Code": "AA"
                        },
                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                            "GMTOffset": -7
                        },
                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                            "eTicket": {
                                "Ind": true
                            }
                        },
                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                        "ElapsedTime": 376,
                        "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                        "MarriageGrp": "O",
                        "Equipment": {
                            "AirEquipType": "32B"
                        },
                        "DepartureDateTime": "2018-07-07T07:00:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-07-07T10:16:00",
                        "FlightNumber": 33,
                        "OnTimePerformance": {
                            "Level": 9
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline": {
                            "FlightNumber": 33,
                            "Code": "AA"
                        },
                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                            "GMTOffset": -4
                        }
                    }],
                    "ElapsedTime": 376
                }, {
                    "FlightSegment": [{
                        "DepartureAirport": {
                            "LocationCode": "LAX"
                        },
                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                            "LocationCode": "JFK"
                        },
                        "MarketingAirline": {
                            "Code": "AA"
                        },
                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                            "GMTOffset": -4
                        },
                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                            "eTicket": {
                                "Ind": true
                            }
                        },
                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                        "ElapsedTime": 335,
                        "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                        "MarriageGrp": "O",
                        "Equipment": {
                            "AirEquipType": "32B"
                        },
                        "DepartureDateTime": "2018-07-09T15:30:00",
                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-07-10T00:05:00",
                        "FlightNumber": 2201,
                        "OnTimePerformance": {
                            "Level": 8
                        },
                        "OperatingAirline": {
                            "FlightNumber": 2201,
                            "Code": "AA"
                        },
                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                            "GMTOffset": -7
                        }
                    }],
                    "ElapsedTime": 335
                }]
            },
            "DirectionInd": "Return"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "ValidatingCarrier": {
                "Code": "AA"
            }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": 3,
        "AirItineraryPricingInfo": {
            "PTC_FareBreakdowns": {
                "PTC_FareBreakdown": {
                    "FareBasisCodes": {
                        "FareBasisCode": [{
                            "BookingCode": "B",
                            "DepartureAirportCode": "JFK",
                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "LAX",
                            "content": "QUAJZNB3"
                        }, {
                            "BookingCode": "B",
                            "DepartureAirportCode": "LAX",
                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "JFK",
                            "content": "QUAJZNB3"
                        }]
                    },
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                        "Quantity": 1,
                        "Code": "ADT"
                    },
                    "PassengerFare": {
                        "FareConstruction": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": "249.30"
                        },
                        "TotalFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "Amount": "296.40"
                        },
                        "Taxes": {
                            "TotalTax": {
                                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                "Amount": "47.10"
                            },
                            "Tax": [{
                                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 1,
                                "TaxCode": "AY",
                                "Amount": 11.2
                            }, {
                                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 1,
                                "TaxCode": "US1",
                                "Amount": 18.7
                            }, {
                                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                "Amount": 9
                            }, {
                                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 1,
                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                "Amount": 8.2
                            }]
                        },
                        "BaseFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "Amount": "249.30"
                        },
                        "EquivFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": "249.30"
                        }
                    },
                    "Endorsements": {
                        "NonRefundableIndicator": true
                    }
                }
            },
            "FareInfos": {
                "FareInfo": [{
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "Cabin": {
                            "Cabin": "Y"
                        },
                        "SeatsRemaining": {
                            "BelowMin": false,
                            "Number": 7
                        }
                    },
                    "FareReference": "B"
                }, {
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "Cabin": {
                            "Cabin": "Y"
                        },
                        "SeatsRemaining": {
                            "BelowMin": false,
                            "Number": 7
                        }
                    },
                    "FareReference": "B"
                }]
            },
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "DivideInParty": {
                    "Indicator": false
                }
            },
            "ItinTotalFare": {
                "FareConstruction": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                    "Amount": "249.30"
                },
                "TotalFare": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                    "Amount": "296.40"
                },
                "Taxes": {
                    "Tax": [{
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                        "TaxCode": "TOTALTAX",
                        "Amount": "47.10"
                    }]
                },
                "BaseFare": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                    "Amount": "249.30"
                },
                "EquivFare": {
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                    "Amount": "249.30"
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

its small part of json, this part repeated up to ten or more time, anybody please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create function first:

```
public DataTable JsonStringToDataTable(string jsonString)
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      string[] jsonStringArray = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");
      List<string> ColumnsName = new List<string>();
      foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
      {
         string[] jsonStringData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
         foreach (string ColumnsNameData in jsonStringData)
         {
            try
            {
               int idx = ColumnsNameData.IndexOf(":");
               string ColumnsNameString = ColumnsNameData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
               if (!ColumnsName.Contains(ColumnsNameString))
               {
                  ColumnsName.Add(ColumnsNameString);
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", ColumnsNameData));
            }
         }
         break;
      }
      foreach (string AddColumnName in ColumnsName)
      {
         dt.Columns.Add(AddColumnName);
      }
      foreach (string jSA in jsonStringArray)
      {
         string[] RowData = Regex.Split(jSA.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
         DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
         foreach (string rowData in RowData)
         {
            try
            {
               int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
               string RowColumns = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
               string RowDataString = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
               nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               continue;
            }
         }
         dt.Rows.Add(nr);
      }
      return dt;
   }
```

Call this function:

```
Datatabel dt = JsonStringToDataTable(JsonString) // put your json string here
```

Comment: i have tried this code but its partially converting the json. Fare info part is not getting converted

Comment: Please make sure your JSON is valid.

Comment: yes i have check that, given json is just a part of the large one i have working with the whole one